# Generic string replacement in a files

Tags: python

I'm looking for a generic way to replace string in a file.
I have a file (which can be `.txt`, `.bat`, `.xml`)
and I want to replace a specific string, e.g. `"ABC"`, by another string, e.g. `"EFG"`

I've tried this:

```py
def replace_in_file(file):
        s = open(file).read()
        s = s.replace("ABC" ,"EFG")
        f = open(file,'w')
        f.write(s)
        f.close()
```

I've also tried this:

```py
def replace_in_file(file):
    with fileinput.FileInput(file) as file:
        for line in file:
                line.replace("ABC" , "EFG")
```

But none of them haven't worked!

I want to automate the process below: instructions

```
Open file with notepad++
Press ctrl+f
go to replace
and replace "ABC" by "EFG"
```

Comment: In your first function, did you close the file after reading it?

Comment: Hi Joevin, your first function looks correct. But how do you call it? Please *edit your question* to include that part of the code, and explain what happens when "it doesn't work": Do you get an error message? An empty file? What?

Comment: You forgot to `print(line)` in the second try.

Comment: Hi @tripleee it seems to work in the terminal i have the correct change but it dosn't change in the file

Comment: Because you didn't pass `inplace=True` either.

Answer (score 0):

I think in a file you cannot replace directly, so you have to write also. Otherwise the change data will not be there. So you can also create a temp file and write over there or you can change the original file. So your both functions are correct, just add something like..

```
tempFile = open( fileToSearch, 'r+' )

for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ): 
    tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )

tempFile.close()
```

Comment: `fileinput` does exactly this for you simply by adding `inplace=True`

Comment: Ok thanks it work !

Comment: That's good and you welcome